# Is there a numpy "max minus min" function?

Tags: python, numpy, max, min

Is there a numpy function that gives for a given numpy array its maximum - minimum value, i.e. numpy.max(a) - numpy.min(a) ?

e.g.

```
numpy.xxx([4,3,2, 6] = 4 since max = 6, min = 2, 6 - 4 = 2)
```

Reason: performance increase since max and min would cause twice the iteration of the array (which is in my case 7.5 million or more numbers).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Indeed there is such a function -- it's called [`numpy.ptp()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) for "peak to peak".

Comment: Internally the `ptp` function computes the minimum and maximum separately, so this solution still iterates over the array twice.  See [the ptp source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e7fe68ad3ce7f91cb152df49115f353ba9d75789/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L308) for details.