# How does one test if a matrix in Python has only 1's and 0's?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I've got a matrix like this:

```
mat1 = np.array([1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]);
```

I want to test if `mat1` contains only 1's or 0's, namely some 1's and some 0's, all 0's, or all 1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> def check(matrix):
...     # flatten up the matrix into one single list
...     # and set on the list it should be [0,1] if it
...     # contains only 0 and 1. Then do sum on that will 
...     # return 1
...     if sum(set(sum(matrix,[]))) > 1:
...         return False
...     return True
...
>>>
>>> check([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]])
True
>>> check([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,2]])
False
>>> check([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,3]])
False
>>>
```

Comment: Could you comment your code? What is happening here?

Comment: Hey, just an aside, how can I make a matrix like `mat0 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` flatten to an array like `arr0 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`?

Comment: Is that what your code does? I think I follow. That's clever... Can I modify your existing set code to do what I want with the matrix-to-array comment I made above?

Comment: I've got a better one: `sum((set(mat0.ravel())))`

Comment: This makes **no** use of numpy, so is waaaay slower.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html), [`numpy.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

- all 0: `np.all(mat == 0)`
- all 1: `np.all(mat == 1)`
- some 0: `np.any(mat == 0)`
- some 1: `np.any(mat == 1)`

---

```
>>> mat1 = np.array([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]])
>>> mat2 = np.array([[0,1,0], [0,0,1], [1,1,1]])

>>> np.all(mat1 == 0)
False
>>> np.any(mat1 == 0)
True
>>> np.all(mat1 == 1)
False
>>> np.any(mat1 == 1)
True

>>> mat3 = mat1 + mat2
>>> mat3
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>> np.all(mat3 == 1)
True
```

**UPDATE**

To check whether the array contains only `1` or `0`, nothing else, use following:

```
>>> mat1 = np.array([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]])
>>> mat2 = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]])
>>> np.all((mat1 == 0) | (mat1 == 1))
True
>>> np.all((mat2 == 0) | (mat2 == 1))
False
```

Comment: Can you please explain what that means?

Comment: @user3333975, I added an example, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I mean, what if I add them and all but one is 0 while the rest are 1's? I don't follow--yet.

Comment: @user3333975, `mat1 == 0` returns array that consist of `True`, `False` items. `numpy.all` returns True only if all items are True. `numpy.any` returns if there's any True.

Comment: @user3333975, Let's call the added array as `a`, and it contains 8 `1` and 1 `0` as items. `numpy.all(a == 0) == False`, `numpy.all(a == 1) == False`, `numpy.any(a == 0) == True`, `numpy.any(a == 1) == True`.

Comment: @user3333975, Sorry, I don't understand what the `bust` mean. (I'm not a native speaker). It would be great if you explain what the word `bust` mean here.

Comment: The matrix has to have only 1's and 0's--in ANY combination. If I add matrices together and I get an integer in any cell that is not 1 or 0, then this is considered a bad result--a "bust." I want to detect if any given matrix has only 1's and 0's for each element.

Comment: Can you method detect if `mat1` contains only 1's and 0's?

Comment: @user3333975, I see. I misunderstood your question. Here's the solution you want: `np.all((mat1 == 0) | (mat1 == 1))`. I will update the answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
In [6]:

set((mat1+mat2).ravel()).issubset(set((1,0)))
Out[6]:
True

In [7]:

mat3 = np.array([[0,5,0], [0,0,1], [1,1,1]])
set((mat1+mat3).ravel()).issubset(set((1,0)))
Out[7]:
False
```

Comment: Add `mat1` and `mat2` together, `ravel()` means to return a flattened view (1 dimension). Then we make a `set()` out of it. When the set of the resulting array is `set((1))`, `set((1,0))` or `set((0))`, the resulting set is a subset of the `set((1,0))`, which means the resulting array only have 1 and 0's. See the new example added.

Comment: If you use Python 2.7+ or 3.1+, you can use set literals: `{1, 0}` instead of `set((1, 0))`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly @falsetru, actually I am on 2.7.6, but just thinking the old fashioned way may be better understood.

Answer (score 1):

**If you know it's int dtype**, then (suprisingly) it's faster to check the max and min (even without [doing these operations simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200580/numpy-function-for-simultaneous-max-and-min)):

```
In [11]: m = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10))

In [12]: %timeit np.all((m == 0) | (m == 1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit m.dtype == int and m.min() == 0 and m.max() == 1
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.8 µs per loop

In [21]: m = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10000, 10000))

In [22]: %timeit np.all((m == 0) | (m == 1))
1 loops, best of 3: 705 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit m.dtype == int and m.min() == 0 and m.max() == 1
1 loops, best of 3: 481 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note: this short circuits if min is not 0.

Comment: pretty nice. And if it wasn't of int dtype, you would have issues using the equality operator as done in all other answers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
import numpy as np
mat1 = np.array([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0]])

np.unique(mat1)
# array([0, 1])
1 in np.unique(mat1)
# True
0 in np.unique(mat1)
# True
np.unique(mat1) == [0, 1]
# array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You can also use [`setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
np.setdiff1d(mat1, [0, 1])
# array([], dtype=int64)
np.setdiff1d(mat1, [0, 1]).size
# 0
```

Comment: Note: np.unique sorts, not an issue here (although this is slower than top soln already) but is if it's got lots of items.

Comment: fyi, pandas unique function does exactly the same as numpy but without the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: `np.sum(np.unique(mat0.ravel()))`

---

So, `mat0.ravel()` does this:

```
[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,0]] ---> [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

This new object is an array, namely the `[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]` object above. Now, `np.unique(mat0.ravel())` finds all the unique elements and sorts them and puts them in a set, like this:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0] ---> {0,1}
```

From here if one applies `np.sum` on this, namely `np.sum(np.unique(mat0.ravel()))` we get the sum of the contents of the set, so a good condition to check if only a `0` or `1` in each and every cell in matrix is the following:

```
np.sum(np.unique(mat0.ravel())) > 1
```

---

*n.b.* - This is only for non-negative integers.