# How to compress a matrix into an array/set in NumPy the fastest?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, set

How can I make a matrix like `mat0 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` flatten to an array like `arr0 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`? Or perhaps a set?

Comment: What are you doing this for, why do you want a flat array / set? (what's the next step?)

Comment: @AndyHayden, I just wanted to be able to do this: `sum((set(mat0.ravel())))`

Comment: It would have been **much** better just to ask that as your question!

Comment: I like to ask question--not always though--that are vague enough to simultaneously be answerable for my own agenda, while also providing a foundational starting point for people who land on this page.

Comment: ok, there is better way to get to that solution though!

Comment: Let me know if you ask that question :p Basically answer is to stay in numpy (no need to use set) so will be 15x (at least) faster.

Comment: @AndyHayden, what? Why not just put it here?

Comment: @AndyHayden, there. How's that? See my title change... ^_^ Wait, never mind. Saw the comments below. It's just `np.sum(np.unique(mat0.ravel()))`, right?

Comment: @AndyHayden, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22241320/3333975

Comment: yep, pandas' pd.unique is actually faster since it doesn't sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mat0 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> mat0.reshape(-1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

or [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
>>> mat0.ravel()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: What does the -1 indicate? Which is faster?

Comment: How do you convert arrays to sets? Like, what if I want the following `[1,1,0]`--->`[1,0]`?

Comment: @user3333975, It's like specifying `9`. If you specify `-1`, the value is infered by the remaining dimensions.

Comment: @user3333975, Do you mean `set(mat0.reshape(-1))` or `set(mat0.ravel())` ?

Comment: I see, I'm dealing with non-square matrices that change their dimensions often.

Comment: "Do you mean set(mat0.reshape(-1)) or set(mat0.ravel())?" <--- Yes

Comment: @user3333975, If you want to get only unique values, use `numpy.unique` instead of `set`: `np.unique(np.array([1,2,3,3]))`.

Comment: @user3333975, And use `numpy.sum` or `sum` method of the array instead of Python builtin function `sum`.