# Is there a "reverse clip" function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have working code, but am wondering if there is a `numpy` implementation for it. This more for satisfying my curiosity and about optimising and making code prettier; I don't have an acute problem. Still, I guess this situation is common enough to be interesting to others than just myself.

So, the situation: I'm calculating a value many times in a loop, and would like to only save the minimum and maximum value.

Initially, I used

```
import numpy as np
vals = []
for obj in objects:
    #...do stuff...
    vals.append(obj.calc_value())
    #...do more stuff
minmax = [np.min(vals), np.max(vals)]
```

which works and is nice and short. However, because I'm storing *all* values, yet only need the min and max, this seems like a waste of perfectly good memory space. Therefore I changed it to

```
import numpy as np
minmax = [np.inf, -np.inf]
for obj in objects:
    #...do stuff...
    val = obj.calc_value()
    if val < minmax[0]:
        minmax[0] = val
    if val > minmax[1]:
        minmax[1] = val
    #...do more stuff
```

which also work, but is a bit verbose. Sure, I could extract the four lines in the code into a function I guess, but...

I couldn't help but wonder, if there isn't a `numpy` function for this. Something like a "reverse" `clip` function. A function which, like `clip`, compares a value to an interval. But which does not return the (possibly changed) value so that it lies in the provided interval (which is what `clip` does), but rather returns the (possibly extended) interval that is needed so that the provided value lies in it.

```
import numpy as np
minmax = [np.inf, -np.inf]
for obj in objects:
    #...do stuff...
    minmax = np.reverse_clip(minmax, obj.calc_value())
    #...do more stuff
```

If there is, I'd love to hear about it. Also, any ideas how I could have found it without asking here? I looked at `numpy`'s array methods, but couldn't find it there.

Comment: I guess I could change the 4 lines into 2, with `minmax[0] = min(minmax[0], val)`. That's better already, but I'm still curious about a `numpy` implementation.

Comment: Similar question: [numpy: function for simultaneous max() and min()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200580/numpy-function-for-simultaneous-max-and-min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the sign on the first item and apply `max` on both, then change it back after the loop:

```
for obj in objects:
    i = obj.calc_value()
    minmax= map(max, zip([-i, i], minmax)) # using python
    minmax = np.vstack((minmax, [-i, i])).max(0) #using numpy
minmax *= np.array([-1, 1]) #using numpy
minmax = [i * j for i, j in zip(a1, [-1, 1])] # using python, or do list(a1) * np.array([-1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks @Mstaino for your answer! I wouldn't call it more readable, but it's definitely creative ;) I probably should have been more clear in my question but, due to the `[-i, i]` list, it's unfortunately not possible to forgo using a temporary variable here.

Comment: You can replace `[-i, i]` with `np.array([-1, 1]) * obj.calc_value()` to eliminate the temporary variable

Comment: I personally find the `map` + `zip` combination very readable, and more performant for small operations. The `vstack` option less so, it is just to give you a different alternative