# Cython min and max on Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I want to speed up a quite simple Python code by converting some functions into cython.
However, in the loop body, I need to find the min and max values of an array and that seems to be the critical point. According to the .html file, these lines need to be translated into very much c-code.. Why is that?

That is the entire code, below I list the lines that give me headaches:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound


@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
cdef box_overlaps_contour(unsigned int[:] boxTopLeftXY, unsigned int boxSize, unsigned int[:, :, :] contourData):
    cdef bint isOverlapping = False
    cdef unsigned int xmin, xmax, width, boxXmin, boxXmax, ymin, ymax, height, boxYmin, boxYmax

    xmin = min(contourData[:, 0, 1])
    xmax = max(contourData[:, 0, 1])
    width = xmax - xmin
    boxXmin = boxTopLeftXY[0]
    boxXmax = boxTopLeftXY[0] + boxSize

    if xmin > (boxXmin-width/2):
        if xmax < (boxXmax+width/2):
            ymin = min(contourData[:, 0, 1])
            ymax = max(contourData[:, 0, 1])
            height = ymax - ymin
            boxYmin = boxTopLeftXY[1]
            boxYmax = boxTopLeftXY[1] + boxSize

            if ymin > (boxYmin-height/2):
                if ymax < (boxYmax+width/2):
                    isOverlapping = True

    return isOverlapping


@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def def_get_indices_of_overlapping_particles(contours not None, unsigned int[:, :] topLefts, unsigned int boxSize):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef unsigned int counter, numParticles, numTopLefts
    numParticles = len(contours)
    numTopLefts = topLefts.shape[0]
    cdef unsigned int[:] overlappingIndices = np.zeros(numParticles, dtype=np.uint32)
    cdef unsigned int[:, :, :] currentContour

    counter = 0
    for i in range(numParticles):
        currentContour = contours[i]
        for j in range(numTopLefts):
            if box_overlaps_contour(topLefts[j, :], boxSize, currentContour):
                overlappingIndices[counter] = i
                counter += 1
                break

    return overlappingIndices[:counter]
```

The function takes a list of contours (np.ndarray, as retrieved from cv2) and an array, representing a certain number of xy-Coordinates, where rectangles are placed with the indicated boxsize. The function is supposed to iterate through the contours and return the indices of contours that are overlapping with one of the boxes.
These lines here seem to make the entire process horribly slow (it is, in fact, slower than the purely Python version..):

```
+13:     xmin = min(contourData[:, 0, 1])
+14:     xmax = max(contourData[:, 0, 1])
```

and, similarly:

```
+21:             ymin = min(contourData[:, 0, 1])
+22:             ymax = max(contourData[:, 0, 1])
```

Other lines that are problematic (but a little less) without me understanding why:

```
+48:             if box_overlaps_contour(topLefts[j, :], boxSize, currentContour):
```

Why is the function call already so complicated? The data types match, everything is unsigned integer..

And also already returning the bool value; I expanded what the compiler made out of it:

```
+31:     return isOverlapping
  __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_r);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(__pyx_v_isOverlapping); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 31, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __pyx_r = __pyx_t_2;
  __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  goto __pyx_L0;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! I still don't really understand how cython works, as it seems :/
If required, I can give further information!

Many thanks!!! :)

EDIT: Here is what Cython makes out of the np.min() line...: Any ideas?

```
+21:             ymin = np.min(contourData[:, 0, 1])
      __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
      __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_n_s_min); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
      __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
      __pyx_t_4.data = __pyx_v_contourData.data;
      __pyx_t_4.memview = __pyx_v_contourData.memview;
      __PYX_INC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_4, 0);
      __pyx_t_4.shape[0] = __pyx_v_contourData.shape[0];
__pyx_t_4.strides[0] = __pyx_v_contourData.strides[0];
    __pyx_t_4.suboffsets[0] = -1;

{
    Py_ssize_t __pyx_tmp_idx = 0;
    Py_ssize_t __pyx_tmp_stride = __pyx_v_contourData.strides[1];
        if ((0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
        __pyx_t_4.data += __pyx_tmp_idx * __pyx_tmp_stride;
}

{
    Py_ssize_t __pyx_tmp_idx = 1;
    Py_ssize_t __pyx_tmp_stride = __pyx_v_contourData.strides[2];
        if ((0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
        __pyx_t_4.data += __pyx_tmp_idx * __pyx_tmp_stride;
}

__pyx_t_2 = __pyx_memoryview_fromslice(__pyx_t_4, 1, (PyObject *(*)(char *)) __pyx_memview_get_unsigned_int, (int (*)(char *, PyObject *)) __pyx_memview_set_unsigned_int, 0);; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
      __PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_4, 1);
      __pyx_t_4.memview = NULL;
      __pyx_t_4.data = NULL;
      __pyx_t_5 = NULL;
      if (CYTHON_UNPACK_METHODS && unlikely(PyMethod_Check(__pyx_t_3))) {
        __pyx_t_5 = PyMethod_GET_SELF(__pyx_t_3);
        if (likely(__pyx_t_5)) {
          PyObject* function = PyMethod_GET_FUNCTION(__pyx_t_3);
          __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_5);
          __Pyx_INCREF(function);
          __Pyx_DECREF_SET(__pyx_t_3, function);
        }
      }
      __pyx_t_1 = (__pyx_t_5) ? __Pyx_PyObject_Call2Args(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_5, __pyx_t_2) : __Pyx_PyObject_CallOneArg(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_2);
      __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_t_5); __pyx_t_5 = 0;
      __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
      if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
      __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
      __pyx_t_6 = __Pyx_PyInt_As_unsigned_int(__pyx_t_1); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_6 == (unsigned int)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
      __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
      __pyx_v_ymin = __pyx_t_6;
```

Comment: There's already a long discussion here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200580/numpy-function-for-simultaneous-max-and-min ; make sure you read all the answers,as even the one with a score of 3 is great.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.min` and `np.max` will probably be quicker than the Python `min` and `max` functions (possibly depending on the size of the array). The Numpy functions will use the C buffer protocol and operate on the C numeric type while the Python ones will use the Python iterator protocol and the numbers will be treated as Python objects. Despite that they'll look just as yellow in Cython.

*Edit:* if that doesn't help you may want to write your own `cdef` function to do `minmax` (to avoid the Python call). Something like (untested code follows...)

```
# return type is a C struct of 2 values - this should be quick...
cdef (double, double) minmax(double arr[:]):
    cdef double min = np.inf
    cdef double max = -np.inf
    cdef int i
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i] < min:
            min = arr[i]
        if arr[i] > max
            max = arr[i]
    return min, max
```

That has the advantage of doing both in one loop, and not requiring a Python function call. It obviously has the disadvantage that you need to write it yourself.

A lot of the generated C code you see is to do with the memoryview slicing, and isn't actually too slow (although it takes up a lot of space).

---

```
cdef box_overlaps_contour(unsigned int[:] boxTopLeftXY, unsigned int boxSize, unsigned int[:, :, :] contourData):
```

No return type is specified so it returns as Python object. You could do `cdef bint box_overlaps_contour(...)` to return a "boolean integer".

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the return type!
Changing to np.min and np.max didn't really change anything. The arrays are not very large, maybe a few hundred numbers at most...

I added to my original question what cython makes out of one np.min(..) line (due to character limit in that comment here)

Comment: I've edited in a suggestion for what to do with `min` and `max` instead (write your own and avoid the call to a Python function). Don't too worried about the amount of code for indexing a memoryview.