# What is the fastest way to find the min and max value of a large multidimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have a numpy array consisting of 20,000 RGB images of 220x220 pixels each. The array, `X_data`, therefore has the shape `(20000, 220, 220, 3)`.

I'm looking for the fastest way to find the minimum and maximum pixel values across the entire dataset. I appreciate this type of task will take time because I'm searching through approximately 3 billion pixel values, but I'm hoping to improve on the solutions I have found already; which are the following:

#### Option 1: Flatten the array

Use `np.flatten` and then `np.min` and `np.max` on the resulting array:

```
flat = X_data.flatten()
np.min(flat)
np.max(flat)
```

This method took a total of 13min 11s (wall time) to find the min and max values.

#### Option 2: List comprehension

Use `np.amin` and `np.amax` to find the min and max for each image, append them to a list, and then find the min and max of that list:

```
min_val = np.min([np.amin(X_data[i]) for i in np.arange(X_data.shape[0])])
max_val = np.max([np.amax(X_data[i]) for i in np.arange(X_data.shape[0])])
```

This method took a total of 8 minutes (wall time).

Are there any faster methods for completing this task?

#### EDIT:

I forgot to mention in the original formulation of the question that I would like this to work on image datasets that have not been rescaled, ie those that contain images of varying sizes. This means that using `np.min` and `np.max` will not work, even though it is faster that the above options.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have a decent multi-core CPU? What OS do you run?

Comment: I'm just using an off the shelf MacBook Air 2020 running Catalina with 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5.

Comment: So do you mean that your opening statement is incorrect... that *"the images are 220x220 each"*?

Comment: Well, the images are 220x220 in the test case described, but I'm hoping for a general solution that works when this is not so.

Comment: What does "image datasets that have not been rescaled, ie those that contain images of varying sizes" have to do with it? Why does that exclude `np.min` and `np.max`?

Comment: I guess one could look up the sources of np.min/np.max and save another factor of 2 by calculating min and max at the same time. Just write yourself a np.minmax function.

Answer (score 5):

If maximum speed is important, it might be worth while adding in a library that can get the maximum and minimum values at the same time. Such a routine would only need to traverse the large array once instead of twice. Since getting these values is completely memory-limited on any modern platform (the computation is minimal), halving memory access is likely to halve execution time. Basically, you can get both values for the price of one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12200671/7328782) has a Fortran implementation linked into Python, and found that the Numpy function was excessively slow also. But that's an 8-year old answer, things have likely improved in the Numpy implementation.

[DIPlib](https://diplib.org) is an image processing library (I'm an author), and since I have it already installed it was easy for me to try out its function to get both the max and min value in an array. I'm using a smaller array than in the OP, I don't want to wait that long for the experiment to finish. Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip
import time

X = np.random.randn(2000, 220, 220, 3)

t = time.time()
np.min(X), np.max(X)
print(time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
dip.MaximumAndMinimum(X)
print(time.time() - t)
```

Median over three runs (without changing the `X` array) gives 0.361s for the first section, and 0.135s for the second section.

Answer (score 4):

The first approach is slower due to the `flatten`, which generates a copy of your data. In your case, the data is large, so a large portion of the runtime will be for memory allocation.

On the other hand, `np.min` by default will check along all axes, e.g.:

```
np.min([[1,2],[3,4]])
# out: 1
```

So you can just do:

```
min_val, max_val = np.min(X_data), np.max(X_data)
```

should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `np.min` is indeed faster, but the problem is that it only works if all the images are the same size. I'm looking for a general solution that works across arrays that include different image sizes, but I didn't make this clear in my question so I'll make an edit to that effect.

Comment: @celery_gemini in which case, only the second option works. Note that numpy operations only work best on homogeneous data, which isn’t the case here as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the max (or the min) requires sorting the values. When both are needed, calling `np.max()` and then `np.min()` makes it sort the values twice...

I prefer simply using this :

```
the_min, the_max = np.percentile(my_data,[0,100])
```

which sorts the data once only...

Comment: Finding min/max doesn't require any sorting as you only have to traverse through the array once.