# How to check if a set of numbers is included in a larger range of numbers?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a set of numbers arranged in a numpy array:

```
large_set = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I have three smaller sets:

```
small_set_1 = np.array([4.65, 4.66, 4.88])
small_set_2 = np.array([6.32, 6.77, 6.98, 7.46])
small_set_3 = np.array([9.75, 9.99, 10.34])
```

Is there any direct way to determine in python that `small_set_x` falls within `large_set` or not?

I did like this but its not very direct:

```
if (min(small_set_1) > min(large_set) or min(small_set_1) > max(large_set)): 
    pass
elif (min(small_set_1) < min(large_set) or min(small_set_1) < max(large_set)):
    pass
elif (max(small_set_1) > min(large_set) or max(small_set_1) > max(large_set)): 
    pass
elif (max(small_set_1) < min(large_set) or max(small_set_1) < max(large_set)):
    pass
```

In the end, I should simply `print("The small set is within the large set")`. If possible, it can be nice to be able to print something like `'The small range doesn't lie in the large set, they are at the beginning of the large_set'` (matches `small_set_1` in this case).

Comment: Will the arrays always be sorted?

Comment: I am confused. You mentioned small_set_2 but in your sample code they are all small_set_1

Comment: The small set is within the large set only if `large.min() < small.min() and large.max() > small.max()`. That should be all you need to check. What are all the other conditions for?

Comment: yes the arrays are always sorted..and the i try for each small_set starting with small_set_1. Ofcourse, small_set_2 is within the large set.

Comment: If the arrays are ***guaranteed*** to be sorted, then you can just do `if large[0] <= small[0] and small[-1] <= large[-1]`. I would post that as an answer but your `elif`s confuse me so I'm not sure what the question is...

Comment: Assuming that the arrays are sorted we can check to see if the first value of the small is larger than the first value of the large, and the same for the last element of each.

Comment: Could you please write it an answer because `large.min() < small.min() and large.max() > small.max()` works! Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200580/numpy-function-for-simultaneous-max-and-min

Comment: It would be nice it `numpy.array` could return `minmax`, but it's an open issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the blue box is the small set and the red box is the large set.
[image]

The small set is completely within the large set only if the minimum of the large set is less than the minimum of the small one **AND** the maximum of the large set is greater than the maximum of the small one. In python, `large.min() < small.min() and large.max() > small.max()`.

Like [@Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo) says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202295/how-to-check-if-a-set-of-of-numbers-is-within-a-large-range-of-numbers/65202438#comment115271061_65202295), if the arrays are pre-sorted, the first element is the minimum and the last element is the maximum, so all you need is `large[0] < small[0] and large[-1] > small[-1]`.

The other `if..elif` conditions cover the other cases:

1. `large.min() > small.min() and large.max() > small.max()` [image]
2. `large.min() < small.min() and large.max() < small.max()` [image]
3. `large.min() > small.min() and large.max() < small.max()` (the "small" set isn't really smaller in this case) [image]

Your problem is that you use the `or` condition instead of the `and` condition, which returns `True` if *any of the conditions* are `True`, and that you mixed up the `min` and `max` calls. You only ever need to compare the two `min`s with each other and the two `max`es with each other to check for overlap.

For non-overlapping sets, you need to compare the `min` of one to the `max` of the other.

4. `large.max() < small.min()` (Obviously `large.min()` is less than `small.max()`, so no need to check)
   [image]
5. `large.min() > small.max()` (Obviously `large.max()` is greater than `small.min()`, so no need to check)
   [image]

Comment: Is there also a way to know..for small_set_1, print('the range doesnt lie in the large set, they are at the begining of the large_set) and for small_set_2, print('the range doesnt lie in the large set, they are at the end of the large_set)

Comment: Wow! +1 for the visual demonstrations!!! Love it. And without intending, you just answered the above comment by OP

Comment: @Tomerikoo haha, I saw their comment and tailored my edit to answer it. Thanks, I'm glad the visual demonstration helps.

Comment: @Lalu the other conditions I listed should help you figure out exactly how `small` and `large` are positioned relative to each other.