# numpy peak tracker function

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running maximum of numpy array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251421/running-maximum-of-numpy-array-values)

Is there a built in numpy function which does this?

```
def peak_track(array):
    max = 0
    max_array = np.zeros_like(array)
    for i, val in enumerate(array):
        if val > max:
            max = val
        max_array[i] = max
    return max_array
```

Comment: Check the documentation and find out !

Comment: obviously I have tried but I can't find it based on my searches, hence the question!

Comment: So you can't find it? If only there was some way to deduce that observation to an answer to your question.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to say. i think it's a fairly reasonable question. there are plenty of similar ones e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312756/is-there-a-numpy-max-min-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713335/peak-finding-algorithm-for-python-scipy

Comment: Those are imho bad questions aswell

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7251421/1240268) however is an exact duplicate :)

Comment: Google `numpy peak detection` and get links to SO and that algorithm : https://gist.github.com/1576079

Comment: thanks hayden, just a case of the name - running maximum was what I was looking for!